# How to make QueryDict instance is mutable in django

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a serialized classs like this:

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # TODO: Define serializer fields here
    bio = BioSerializer()
    designation = GroupListSerializer()
    department = GroupListSerializer()
    #user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'
        # fields = ['user','tax_id_number','account_number','joining_date','designation','department','gender','marital_status','id_type','birthday','ethnicity','preferred_language','phone_number','em_contact','address']


    def create(self,validated_data):
        bio = validated_data.pop('bio')
        designation = validated_data.pop('designation')
        department = validated_data.pop('department')

        new_bio = Bio.objects.create(**bio)

        new_designation = Groups.objects(**designation) 
        new_department = Groups.objects(**department)
        employee = list(Employee.objects.create(designation=new_designation,department=new_department,
                    bio=new_bio,**validated_data))
        employee = json.dumps(employee)
        return employee
```

**And my views are as follows:**

```
class EmployeeRecordView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset=Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class=EmployeeSerializer

    def post(self, request):

        serializer = EmployeeSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=ValueError):
            serializer.create(validated_data=request.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.error_messages,
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The problem is when I try to make a 'POST' request I get the following logs below:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
This QueryDict instance is immutable
```

How do I make `POST`ing successfull. Where am I going wrong with this approach I have implemented above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to call `serializer.create` yourself - I believe the line that is throwing the error is `serializer.create(validated_data=request.data)`. You can try this:

```
...
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
serializer.save()
return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Another thing is when you set `raise_exception=True`, it already throws an error response so you don't need to put it in an `if/else` block.